# How to define own complex WebElement in JDI test framework

Tags: java, selenium, jdi, jdiframework

I define radioButton that [there](https://github.com/epam/JDI/blob/master/Java/Tests/jdi-uitest-webtests/src/main/java/com/epam/jdi/uitests/testing/unittests/custom/CheckListOfTypeOne.java). It work if I initialize element that [there](https://github.com/epam/JDI/blob/b28105bf9deddb4a1ea6db3fdcb58efedf3fac71/Java/Tests/jdi-uitest-webtests/src/main/java/com/epam/jdi/uitests/testing/unittests/pageobjects/pages/MetalsColorsPage.java#L146) But it doesn't work with @FindBy annotation.
I create a constructor:

```
public MyRadioButtons(By optionsNamesLocatorTemplate) {
    super(optionsNamesLocatorTemplate);
    //some code
}
```

When I run tests, I have an error:

> java.lang.AssertionError: Error in getElementInstance for field

How to define them using JDI style and approach?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are returning a MyRadioButtons Object, not WebElement Object.
Try this code :

```
WebElement radioButton = driver.findElement(optionsNamesLocatorTemplate);
```

Comment: Thank you, but
1. RadioButtons - collections of elements.
2. I use JDI. I know as it doing on nativ Selenium. Need example in this framework.